# how can I run a cmake macro in install()?

Tags: cmake

`install(SCRIPT <file>)` can run a cmake script. `install(CODE <code-string>)` can run a cmake command. But it raised `Unknown CMake command` error, when I call a macro in CODE version. Is there any way can let me call a macro/function in `install()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way can let me call a macro/function in install()?

No, inside `install(CODE)` you cannot call a macro/function defined in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

The code provided to `install(CODE)` is executed at *installation* stage, not in *configuration* process when your `CMakeLists.txt` is parsed. So, inside `install(CODE)` the macros and functions defined in your `CMakeLists.txt` are NOT available.

The most CMake can is expand variables while evaluate the parameter to `install(CODE)`.

Comment: This explains everything. Thanks ;)